# Why my peer's computer not able to connect to my PC's Apache server

Tags: apache-http-server

I have an Apache server in my own computer, I can access it through `http://localhost` and `http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx`. Both show me **It works** in the webpage. When my peer trying to connect to my Apache through `http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx`, the browser seems refuse to connect to my Apache.

I usually develop my web app using localhost to test out the result, may I know how can I let my peer to connect to my Apache so that there can look at the result from my local PC without deploy it to the server?

Comment: Testing with `http://localhost` doesn't really test what you want. Test with your local IP address, like `http://192.168.1.32` (or whatever). That will at least make sure your web server is listening to the right address.

Answer (score 1):

most common cause is firewall blocking the connection, to know for sure though you need to more info, eg. can the peer ping the ip address of your machine? do you get a specific error message in ie when trying to access the page, does anything show in your apache logs, etc.

Comment: My peer's computer can ping my IP, and the IE is showing the message "web page can not be display". The Apache error.log is showing favicon.ico does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

What is "your peer"? Is it a computer on the same network ? On the internet ? What ?

In the former case, a firewall blocking port 80 is the most likely cause.
If you're trying to access it from outside your own network, look at your router.

Comment: FYI, it is within the same network. I have tested to use different port number for Apache, it still showing the page can not be display error in the web page. BTW, I don't know how to check whether the port is being blocked?

Comment: to test your ability to access a port on a remote machine, try using a port sniffer (http://sectools.org/tag/sniffers/), wireshark tends to be popular on here though i've not used any myself yet.